# React Docusign Clickwrap Credentials

Tags: reactjs, typescript, amazon-s3, docusignapi

In my react application, when Im rendering the Docusign clickwrap, I need to supply the accountId and the clickwrapId. Is there a secure way to reference the accountId/clickwrapId without actually putting those values in. I dont want to expose those credentials in my react application

```
function App() {
  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    docuSignClick.Clickwrap.render({
      environment: 'https://demo.docusign.net',
      accountId: '...',
      clickwrapId: '...',

      onMustAgree(agreement) {
        // Called when no users have previously agreed by the above client user ID for the most recent required Clickwrap version
      },

      onAgreed(agreement) {
        // Called when either 1) the clientUserId has previously agreed 2) the clientUserId has clicked agree and completed successfully
      },

      onDeclined(agreement) {
        // Called when the clientUserId has declined successfully
      }
    }, '#ds-clickwrap');
  }, []);

  return <div id="ds-clickwrap" />
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah, you can use the server-side API to generate an agreement URL instead if that is desired.

POST `/clickapi/v1/accounts/.../clickwraps/.../agreements`:
Only the `clientUserId` is required to make this API call. You would do this from your server and then pass the URL from the response to the client.

```
{
   "clientUserId": "..."
}
```

This would return an agreement URL to then be used in the snippet of JS:

```
{
   ...
   "status": "created",
   "agreementUrl": "https://...."
}
```

This `agreementUrl` could then be used in the snippet:

```js
docuSignClick.render({
   agreementUrl: '...agreementUrl from REST API response...',

   onAgreed...
}, '#ds-clickwrap');
```

Comment: Where do you see the POST url to get the agreements url? I'm on https://developers.docusign.com/docs/click-api/reference/Accounts/ClickWraps/ and i don't see any POST `/clickapi/v1/accounts/.../clickwraps/.../agreements`

Comment: i cant find that api endpoint POST `/clickapi/v1/accounts/.../clickwraps/.../agreements` on https://developers.docusign.com/docs/click-api/reference/Accounts/ClickWraps/