# DocuSign Click API - Unauthorized response calling POST agreements

Tags: docusignapi

We are currently integrating with the DocuSign click API.  We are are using JSON Web Token Bearer (JWT) grant and the following calls are working fine.

GET `/clickapi/v1/accounts/{accountId}/clickwraps?status=active`

GET `/clickapi/v1/accounts/{accountId}/clickwraps/{clickwrapId}/users?client_user_id=<clientUserID>`

To hide {accountId} and {clickwrapId} from the UI, I was trying to follow this approach [React Docusign Clickwrap Credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64163449/react-docusign-clickwrap-credentials/64164599#64164599)

But I am getting response 401-Unauthorized when I tried to call api POST `/clickapi/v1/accounts/{accountId}/clickwraps/{clickwrapId}/agreements` with body

```json
    {
       "clientUserId": "..."
    }
```

These are the authentication scopes set: `impersonation`,`signature` and `click.manage`.

In [API Documentation](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/click-api/reference/Accounts/ClickWraps/) there is nothing related with that POST api. Is that a valid API? why I am getting 401?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears you also need the `click.send` scope for this Click API endpoint.
I'll request we update the documentation to reflect that. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: You are correct, I was missing `click.send` scope. Now is working fine. Hope DocuSing can update the documentation to add this useful endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

+1 to above. Thank for reporting this issue as well. We're aware that the endpoint you callout above (/clickapi/v1/accounts/{accountId}/clickwraps/{clickwrapId}/agreements) isn't listed under the Clickwrap documentation. We're working on resolving that asap.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add on, this helped resolve the issue I was hitting with error code 401 using DocuSign.Click for CreateHasAgreedWithHttpInfo.  Adding the click.send and click.manage to scope of impersonation authorization, and JWT token request fixed it.  Just received back the response with the Agreement URL.

This is noted in the DocuSign online help information in their development portal.  I just missed it with all the information there.  A bit of an information overload.

:)

Thanks.