# DocuSign EmbedClickwrap.cs -- gets error -- Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0

Tags: docusignapi, docusign-sdk

Thank you for your assistance.

I’m an experienced programmer working with C# for about 5 years.  Currently I am getting deeper into API work.  The current project is a console proof of concept test solution for an API call to DocuSign’s embed an elastic template functionality.  I have a DocuSign developer account with an application, integration, and elastic template setup for use with the below.  Ids, secrets, keys, etc., and the impersonation permission grant was successfully done.

I have followed the examples in DocuSign’s developer support information on their website and in GitHub.   I have double/triple checked what I coded against the examples.  I do not see where this error is coming from or how to resolve it.

I checked the other occurrences of this error, but none seemed to use the newer DocuSign.Click NuGet packages.

What am I missing here?

**SETUP**

- Visual Studio Community Edition 2022, fully updated.
- NuGet packages:

  - DocuSign.Click 1.3.0
  - NewtonSoft.Json 13.0.2

The error occurs in-- “CallClickAPI(clickAccountApi, accountId, clickwrapId, userAgreementRequest)”

When this line is executed—
“ApiResponse<UserAgreementResponse> response = clickAccountApi.CreateHasAgreedWithHttpInfo(
accountId,
clickwrapId,
userAgreementRequest);”

**TEST RUN NARRATIVE**

- Pre run build successful
- Set breakpoint at call to CallClickAPI() method.
- Set breakpoint at Console.WriteLine at end of Main().
- Start debug run.
- Solution successfully receives the access-token.
- Run stops at the first break point.
- Step into till “clickAccountAPi…” is executed.
- Error occurs.

DocuSign.Click.Client.ApiException
HResult=0x80131500
Message=Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.
Source=DocuSign.Click
StackTrace:
at DocuSign.Click.Client.DocuSignClient.Deserialize(DocuSignResponse response, Type type)
at DocuSign.Click.Api.AccountsApi.<CreateHasAgreedAsyncWithHttpInfo>d__25.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at DocuSign.Click.Api.AccountsApi.CreateHasAgreedWithHttpInfo(String accountId, String clickwrapId, UserAgreementRequest userAgreementRequest)
at DocuSignConsoleTester.Program.CallClickAPI(AccountsApi clickAccountApi, String accountId, String clickwrapId, UserAgreementRequest userAgreementRequest) in C:\T\repos\DocuSignConsoleTester\DocuSignConsoleTester\Program.cs:line 87
at DocuSignConsoleTester.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\T\repos\DocuSignConsoleTester\DocuSignConsoleTester\Program.cs:line 37

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DocuSign.Click.Api;
using DocuSign.Click.Client;
using DocuSign.Click.Model;
using DocuSign.Click.Client.Auth;

namespace DocuSignConsoleTester
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string clientId = "xx...xx";
            string userId = "xx...xx";
            string accountId = "xx...xx";
            string authServer = "account-d.docusign.com"; // for demo environment
            string base_path = "https://account-d.docusign.com/"; // for demo environment
            string fullName = "xyz";
            string email = "xyz@gmail.com";
            string company = "xyz at Universe End";
            string title = "xyuz Proprietor ";
            string clickwrapId = "xx...xx";
            DateTime date = DateTime.Now;

            string access_token = GetJwtToken(clientId, userId, accountId, authServer);

            Console.WriteLine("Acess_Token: [" + access_token + "]");

            AccountsApi clickAccountApi = BuildHeader(base_path, access_token);

            UserAgreementRequest userAgreementRequest = BuildUpdateClickwrapHasAgreedRequest( fullName, email, company, title, date);

            ApiResponse<UserAgreementResponse> response = CallClickAPI(clickAccountApi, accountId, clickwrapId, userAgreementRequest);

            Console.WriteLine(" End of test run ");

        }

        public static string GetJwtToken(string clientId, string userId, string accountId, string authServer)
        {
            string oauthBasePath = authServer;
            int expiresInHours = 1;


            //List<string> scopes = new List<string>() { "signature" };
            //List<string> scopes = new List<string>() { "impersonation" };
            List<string> scopes = new List<string>() { "signature impersonation" };
            DocuSignClient dsClient = new DocuSignClient(authServer);
            string rsaKeyBase64 = @"xx...xx==";
            var rsaKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(rsaKeyBase64);
            OAuth.OAuthToken token = dsClient.RequestJWTUserToken(clientId, userId, oauthBasePath, rsaKeyBytes, expiresInHours, scopes);

            return token.access_token.ToString();
        }

        public static AccountsApi BuildHeader(string basePath, string accessToken)
        {
            var apiClient = new DocuSignClient(basePath);
            apiClient.Configuration.DefaultHeader.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
            var clickAccountApi = new AccountsApi(apiClient);

            return clickAccountApi;
        }

        public static UserAgreementRequest BuildUpdateClickwrapHasAgreedRequest(string fullName, string email, string company, string title, DateTime date)
        {
            var userAgreementRequest = new UserAgreementRequest { DocumentData = new Dictionary<string, string>() };
            userAgreementRequest.DocumentData.Add("fullName", fullName);
            userAgreementRequest.DocumentData.Add("email", email);
            userAgreementRequest.DocumentData.Add("company", company);
            userAgreementRequest.DocumentData.Add("title", title);
            userAgreementRequest.DocumentData.Add("date", date.ToString());
            userAgreementRequest.ClientUserId = email;

            return userAgreementRequest;
        }

        public static ApiResponse<UserAgreementResponse> CallClickAPI(AccountsApi clickAccountApi, string accountId, string clickwrapId, UserAgreementRequest userAgreementRequest)
        {
            ApiResponse<UserAgreementResponse> response = clickAccountApi.CreateHasAgreedWithHttpInfo(accountId, clickwrapId, userAgreementRequest);
            
            if (response.StatusCode == 201)
            {
                //return response.Data;
                return response;
            }
            else
            {
                response.Data.AgreementUrl = "Already Agreed";
                return response;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

I did the above debug run.  I was expecting it to return the response information; which would contain the embed URL amongst other information.

Comment: A follow up note.  After this I hit an error for 401, Error calling CreateHasAgreed.  After more research than I would like to claim, I noticed in another StackOverflow ticket () someone had this issue and adding Click.Send and Click.Manage to the scope was needed.

So for DocuSign.Click for CreateHasAgreedWithHttpInfo. Adding the click.send and click.manage to scope of impersonation authorization, and JWT token request fixed it. Just received back the response with the Agreement URL.

This is in the DocuSign online help information in their development portal.  Missed it.

Comment: The other ticket..   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64921514/docusign-click-api-unauthorized-response-calling-post-agreements/75761589#75761589

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is your base_path

```
string base_path = "https://account-d.docusign.com/"
```

This is wrong, should be instead

```
string base_path = "https://demo.docusign.net/clickapi"
```

Comment: Thanks.  Not sure how I missed that.  I did a bunch of searches for what to use for the base-path.   This did get by this error.